# getting the average rgb value of an image in wand

Tags: python, image, rgb, wand, magickwand

I'm wondering if it is possible to calculate the average rgb value in with [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.2/)?

I know how to do it with PIL, but in the docs of wand I can't really find how to get the image data.

The only thing I could find was this:

```
for row in image:
    for col in row:
        assert isinstance(col, wand.color.Color)
        print(col)
```

But then `col` is a `Color` object and I'm not really sure how to extract the values from there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have answered the question with the information you provided :D

if `col` is a `Color` object, then it's as easy as pulling information from the child node like this:

```
col.red
```

Here's my full code (using Python 2). I never used Wand, but this is definitely awesome!

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
from wand.color import Color

with Image(filename='mona-lisa.png') as image:
    for row in image:
        for col in row:
            assert isinstance(col, Color)
            print str(col) + "R:"+str(col.red)+"|"+"G:"+str(col.green)+"|"+"B:"+str(col.blue)
```

So, if you want the average, you can average the reds together, the greens or all of them.

More on the nodes/modules of the Color object can be found here:

[Wand Documentation for Color object](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.2/wand/color.html)